# Function to apply mean on a list of vectors without need to list the vectors (changes to a function call)

Tags: r, function

I have multiple objects and I need to apply some function to them, in my example `mean`. But the function call shouldn't include `list`, it must look like this: `my_function(a, b, d)`.
Advise how to do it please, probably I need `quote` or `substitute`, but I'm not sure how to use them.

```
a <- c(1:15)
b <- c(1:17)
d <- c(1:19)
my_function <- function(objects) {
  lapply(objects, mean)
}
my_function(list(a, b, d))
```

Comment: `my_function <- function(...) lapply(list(...), mean)` if you want to keep the output as a list, `my_function <- function(...) vapply(list(...), mean, 1)` if you want it as a numeric vector. See `?dots`. Consider adding a description of your actual use case to the post, as outcomes could be surprising. For example, `my_function` will happily accept a character vector , even though you might expect it to throw an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution:

```r
a <- c(1:15)
b <- c(1:17)
d <- c(1:19)

my_function <- function(...) {
  lapply(list(...), mean)
}

my_function(a, b, d)

#> [[1]]
#> [1] 8
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 9
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 10
```

Answer (score 1):

To still be able to benefit from the other arguments of `mean` such as `na.rm=` and `trim=`, i.e. to generalize, we may `match` the `formalArgs` with the dots and split the call accordingly.

```
my_function <- function(...) {
  cl <- match.call()
  m <- match(formalArgs(base:::mean.default), names(cl), 0L)
  vapply(as.list(cl)[-c(1L, m)], function(x) {
    eval(as.call(c(quote(base:::mean.default), list(x), as.list(cl[m]))))
  }, numeric(1L))
}

## OP's example
my_function(a, b, d) 
# [1]  8  9 10


## generalization:
set.seed(42)
my_function(rnorm(12), rnorm(5), c(NA, rnorm(3)))
# [1]  0.7553736 -0.2898547         NA

set.seed(42)
my_function(rnorm(12), rnorm(5), c(NA, rnorm(3)), na.rm=TRUE)
# 0.7553736 -0.2898547 -1.2589363 

set.seed(42)
my_function(rnorm(12), rnorm(5), c(NA, rnorm(3)), na.rm=TRUE, trim=.5)
# 0.5185655 -0.2787888 -2.4404669
```

---

*Data:*

```
a <- 1:15; b <- 1:17; d <- 1:19
```

Comment: @Aella Imagine that it separates the vectors from the arguments passed to `mean`, creates a call from that, and evaluates the whole thing.